# Performance issues generating a unique name

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a table 'Objects' present in SQL Server DB. It contains the names (string) of objects.
I have a list of names of new objects that need to be inserted in the 'Objects' table, in a separate table 'NewObjects'. This operation will be referred as 'import' henceforward.

I need to generate a unique name for each record to be imported to 'Objects' from 'NewObjects', if the record name is already present in 'Objects'. This new name will be stored in 'NewObjects' table against the old name.

```
DECLARE @NewObjects TABLE
(
    ...
    Name varchar(20),
    newName nvarchar(20)
)
```

I have implemented a stored procedures which generates unique name for each record to be imported from 'NewObjects'. However, I am not happy with the performance for 1000 records (in 'NewObjects'.)
I want help to optimize my code. Below is the implementation:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[importWithNewNames] @args varchar(MAX)

-- Sample of @args is like 'A,B,C,D' (a CSV string)
...


DECLARE @NewObjects TABLE
(
    _index int identity PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    newName nvarchar(20)
)

-- 'SplitString' function: this is a working implementation which is right now not concern of performance
INSERT INTO @NewObjects (Name)
SELECT * from SplitString(@args, ',')

declare @beg int = 1
declare @end int
DECLARE @oldName varchar(10)

-- get the count of the rows
select @end = MAX(_index) from @NewObjects

while @beg <= @end
BEGIN
    select @oldName = Name from @NewObjects where @beg = _index

    Declare @nameExists int = 0

    -- this is our constant. We cannot change
    DECLARE @MAX_NAME_WIDTH int = 5

    DECLARE @counter int = 1
    DECLARE @newName varchar(10)
    DECLARE @z varchar(10)

    select @nameExists = count(name) from Objects where name = @oldName
    ...
    IF @nameExists > 0
    BEGIN
        -- create name based on pattern 'Fxxxxx'. Example: 'F00001', 'F00002'.
        select @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')

        while EXISTS (select top 1 1 from Objects where name = @newName)
         OR EXISTS (select top 1 1 from @NewObjects where newName = @newName)
        BEGIN
            select @counter = @counter + 1
            select @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')
        END

        select top 1 @z = @newName from Objects

        update @NewObjects
        set newName = @z where @beg = _index
    END

    select @beg = @beg + 1
END

-- finally, show the new names generated
select * from @NewObjects
```

Comment: Doesn't your RDBMS offer this functionality?

Comment: @vonbrand, the optimization packing in Microsoft SQL Server, better known as the Tuner, is capable of taking a query or set of queries and telling you how to optimize your indexes for the work. However, before that's helpful, you need to ensure that the work you're doing is as correct as it can be.

Comment: @vonbrand, have a look at my answer. It concretes the fact that the RDBMS **could not in any way** have assisted the OP in this.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, I'm defintely no expert in SQL or databases, but I understand there are mechanisms for creating, say, correlative numbers for table entries. I'm just wondering why that doesn't fit the bill here.

Comment: @vonbrand, the issue with that approach is that you don't really have anything to `PARTITION` over in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER: I am in no position to *test* these recommendations therefore there may be syntax errors that you'll have to work out on your own as you implement them. They are here as a guide to both fix this procedure but also aid you in growing your skill set for future projects.**

One optimization just skimming through, that would become more prevalent as you iterated over larger sets, is this code here:

```
select @nameExists = count(name) from Objects where name = @oldName
...
IF @nameExists > 0
```

consider changing it to this:

```
IF EXISTS (select name from Objects where name = @oldName)
```

---

Also, rather than doing this:

```
-- create name based on pattern 'Fxxxxx'. Example: 'F00001', 'F00002'.
select @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')

while EXISTS (select top 1 1 from Objects where name = @newName)
 OR EXISTS (select top 1 1 from @NewObjects where newName = @newName)
BEGIN
    select @counter = @counter + 1
    select @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')
END
```

consider this:

```
DECLARE @maxName VARCHAR(20)
SET @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')

SELECT @maxName = MAX(name) FROM Objects WHERE name > @newName ORDER BY name
IF (@maxName IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    @counter = CAST(SUBSTRING(@maxName, 2) AS INT)
    SET @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')
END
```

that will ensure that you're not iterating and doing multiple queries just to find the maximum integer value of the generated name.

Further, based on what little context I have, you should also be able to make one more optimization that will ensure you only have to do the aforementioned one time, **ever**.

```
DECLARE @maxName VARCHAR(20)
SET @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')

IF (@beg = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT @maxName = MAX(name) FROM Objects WHERE name > @newName ORDER BY name
    IF (@maxName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        @counter = CAST(SUBSTRING(@maxName, 2) AS INT)
        SET @newName = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(@counter, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')
    END
END
```

The reason I say you can make that optimization is because unless you have to worry about other entities inserting records during this time **that look like the ones you are** (e.g. Fxxxxx), then you only have to find the MAX one time and can simply ***iterate*** `@counter` over the loop.

***In fact,*** you could actually pull this entire piece *out* of the loop. You should be able to extrapolate that pretty easily. Just pull the `DECLARE` and `SET` of `@counter` out along with the code inside the `IF (@beg = 1)`. ***But take it one step at a time.***

---

Also, change this line:

```
select top 1 @z = @newName from Objects
```

to this:

```
SET @z = @newName
```

because you are ***literally*** running a query to `SET` two local variables. **This is likely a huge cause for the performance issues.** A good practice for you to get into is *unless you're actually setting a variable from a `SELECT` statement*, use the `SET` operation for local variables. There are some other places in your code where this applies, consider this line:

```
select @beg = @beg + 1
```

use this instead:

```
SET @beg = @beg + 1
```

---

Finally, as stated above regarding simply ***iterating*** `@counter`, at the end of the loop where you have this line:

```
select @beg = @beg + 1
```

just add a line:

```
SET @counter = @counter + 1
```

and you're golden!

---

So to recap, you can gather the maximum conflicting name just **one time** so you'll be getting rid of all those iterations. You're going to start using `SET` to get rid of performance ridden lines like `select top 1 @z = @newName from Objects` where you're actually querying a table to set two local variables. And you're going to leverage the `EXISTS` method instead of setting a variable that leveraged an `AGGREGATE` function `COUNT` to do that work.

Let me know how these optimizations work.

Comment: Thanks Michael, we have implemented solution based on your inputs and on a certain size of data, the time reduced from 9 sec to less than 0 sec. We are also thinking about incorporating Frederic's answer : eliminate all loops.

Comment: @Nayan, I'm glad that it reduced it by that much, that's awesome! And yes, if you can avoid looping that's great, but thankfully you weren't using a `CURSOR`, those are more so the kiss of death than a loop. At any rate, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, that was really helpful for us. The performance is improved alot. Now we are able to generate the unique names in less than 0 sec. Once again, I thank you very much for your inputs :)

Comment: @VinodSagar, I'm glad I could be of such assistance! You can mark this as the answer for myself of course, but also for the community!

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid queries inside loops.. Especially if this is in a table variable...

You should try to use a temp table and index this table on newname column. I bet it would improve a bit the performance..

But would be better you rewrite it all avoiding those loop with query inside..

Setting my ambient for test...

```
    --this would be your object table... I feed it with some values for test
    DECLARE @Objects TABLE
    (
        _index int identity PRIMARY KEY,
        Name varchar(20)

    )
    insert into @Objects(name)
    values('A'),('A1'),('B'),('F00001')

    --the parameter of your procedure
    declare @args varchar(MAX)
    set @args = 'A,B,C,D,F00001'

    --@NewObjects2 is your @NewObjects just named the n2 cause I did run your solution together when testing

    DECLARE @NewObjects2 TABLE
    (
        _index int identity PRIMARY KEY,
        Name varchar(20),
        newName nvarchar(20)
    )

    INSERT INTO @NewObjects2 (Name)
    SELECT * from SplitString(@args, ',')

    declare @end int
    select @end = MAX(_index) from @NewObjects2
    DECLARE @MAX_NAME_WIDTH int = 5
```

At this point its very similar your solution

Now what I would do instead your looping

```
--generate newNames in format FXXXXX with free names sufficient to give newnames for all lines in @newObject
--you should alter this to get the greater FXXXXX name inside the Objects and start generate newNames from this point.. to avoid overhead creating newNames that will sure not to be used..
with N_free as 
(
     select 
         0 as [count],
         'F' + REPLACE(STR(0, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0') as [newName],
         0 as fl_free,
         0 as count_free

     union all 

     select 
         N.[count] + 1 as [count],
         'F' + REPLACE(STR(N.[count]+1, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0') as [newName],
         OA.fl_free,
         count_free + OA.fl_free as count_free
     from 
         N_free N
     outer apply 
         (select 
              case 
                 when not exists(select name from @Objects
                                 where Name = 'F' + REPLACE(STR(N.[count]+1, @MAX_NAME_WIDTH, 0), ' ', '0')) 
                    then 1 
                 else 0 
              end as fl_free) OA
    where 
        N.count_free < @end
)
--return only those newNames that are free to be used
    ,newNames as (select  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [count]) as _index_name
                         ,[newName] 
                  from N_free where fl_free = 1
    )
--update the @NewObjects2 giving newname for the ones that got the name already been used on Objects
    update N2
    set newName = V2.[newName]
    from @NewObjects2 N2
    inner join (select V._index,V.Name,newNames.[newName]
                from(   select row_number() over (partition by case when O.Name is not null 
                                                                        then 1
                                                                        else 0
                                                        end 
                                                        order by N._index) as _index_name
                                  ,N._index
                                  ,N.Name
                                  ,case when O.Name is not null 
                                        then 1
                                        else 0
                                    end as [fl_need_newName]
                            from @NewObjects2 N
                            left outer join @Objects O
                            on O.Name = N.Name
                    )V
                    left outer join newNames 
                    on newNames._index_name = V._index_name
                    and V.fl_need_newName = 1
    )V2
    on V2._index = N2._index
            option(MAXRECURSION 0)

    select * from @NewObjects2
```

The results that I achieved was the same then using your solution for this ambient...

You may check if this really generate same result...

The result for this query was

```
    _index  Name    newName
        1   A       F00002
        2   B       F00003
        3   C       NULL
        4   D       NULL
        5   F00001  F00004
```

Comment: Seems nice approach, Frederic. We will test in lab and let you know. But, ideally newName for C and D should not be null.

Comment: You have used recursion, instead of loop. :) Its harder to read for simple programmer, and possibly harder to maintain. We have to measure the efficiency improvements in order to decide whether to use it or not.

Comment: yes, my aim was avoiding the querie on table variable... cause table variable dont have indexes neither statistics... maybe just change to a temporary table with an appropriate index can improve more the performance... when have a huge amount of data on tables... when you decide your solution, let me know what was the better way to solve this

Comment: Thankyou very much @ Frederic for sharing your valuable inputs.